# Data loading in App showing no internet connection

Tags: php, android, json, networking

I am developing an android application in which I need to request to server for data. But the request always returns with the error 'no internet connection', even if I'm connected to wireless network  or personal network. 
Sometimes data is getting but after sending multiple request to server no internet connection message is showing.

Following is the sample code for getting data.

```
public void getPostRequests(final String post_id, final String seeker_count) {
    final List<SeekerItem> seekerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final CommonRecyclerView commonRecyclerView = new CommonRecyclerView(ViewPost.this, ll_req_view_recruiter.getRootView(), null);
    final SeekerAdapter seekerAdapter = new SeekerAdapter(ViewPost.this, coordinatorLayout_view_post, sharedPreferencesDatabase, 1, post_id, seekerItems, commonRecyclerView.getRecyclerView());
    commonRecyclerView.setAdapter(seekerAdapter);
    commonRecyclerView.getFloatingActionButton().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    commonRecyclerView.getRecyclerView().setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    if (!TextUtils.equals(seeker_count, "0")) {
        AndroidNetworking.post(IpConfig.URL_GET_RECRUITER_REQ)
                .addBodyParameter("post_id", post_id)
                .addBodyParameter("last_id", "0")
                .setTag("getPost")
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        commonRecyclerView.getProgressBar().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        commonRecyclerView.getTextView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        seekerItems.addAll(DecodeJson.getSeeker(response, commonRecyclerView.getTextView()));
                        seekerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        commonRecyclerView.getProgressBar().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        commonRecyclerView.getTextView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (TextUtils.equals(anError.getErrorDetail(), "connectionError")) {
                            commonRecyclerView.getTextView().setText("No Internet Connection");
                        } else {
                            commonRecyclerView.getTextView().setText(anError.getErrorDetail());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you are  requesting url  or parameters are wrong. i.e why it is going to onError() instead onResponse().

Comment: but sometimes data is getting

Comment: then check out the url is correct or not before sending request.

Comment: Make sure you have proper permission in your manifest, i.e. `android.permission.INTERNET`